# How to cancel current request in interceptor - Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

As you know it's possible to use **Interceptors** in new versions of Angular 4.

In mine, I want to cancel a request in interceptor in some conditions.
So is it possible? Maybe what I should ask is: which way I should do that?

It'll also be OK if I find a way to rewrite some response to the request instead of canceling it.

Comment: What do you mean by "rewrite some response"? It is easy to edit a request before handling it, if that's what you mean.

Comment: The documentation has an example: https://angular.io/guide/http#caching

Comment: I mentioned this because of some features in angularjs that I saw in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38926333/3534952.

Comment: @JBNizet I reviewed the documentation over and over again! I think this one is not mentioned in documentation or maybe I can not see it! What I want I exactly is cancel a request or maybe rewrite another response instead of what will get from server.

Comment: The documentation I linked to has the following comment: *A cached response exists. Serve it instead of forwarding the request to the next handler.* So it does return a cached response instead of actually sending the request to the server.

Comment: But what if the cache not exist? @JBNizet

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I think all you have to do to cut the interceptor chain is to simply return an empty `Observable` like so:

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  if (stopThisRequest) {
    return EMPTY;
  }

  return next.handle(request);
}
```

Comment: In a scenario, where let's say I have two rxJS requests executing simultaneously to the backend, and I want to stop one of them, how can I do that with interceptor? @RVP

Comment: for RXJS 6 simply import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs' and return EMPTY. FYI, in rxjs EMPTY is different than empty.

Comment: How to cancel response while intercepting response in httpclient, Observable.empty() is not working

Comment: @Codehan25 that logic you have to come up with your self. You can use DI to inject any service you want in the interceptor and base your logic on state available in your application

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for, helped me a lot :)

Comment: @RVP I can able to break chain but I have to resolve this request with error before  breaking, I tried throwerror() and pass Http error obj but didn't work, Can you help me on thiis?

Comment: If we had a reactive solution, two streams, how would it be done? 
- I thought of using next.handle(request).combineLatestWith(obs$).pipe(logic)

Answer (score 13):

This is just a slight variant of [RVP's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3878674/rvp) answer

```
import { NEVER } from 'rxjs';

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  if (stopThisRequest) {
    return NEVER;
  }

  return next.handle(request);
}
```

I used `NEVER` instead of `EMPTY` to avoid dealing with undefined values in my subscriptions (or promises).

Use `NEVER` if you don't want your subscription callback to be invoked

Comment: By using this in angular universal, the app will stuck and keep waiting the request resolved.

Comment: Use Of({}), Of() or EMPTY, throwError, NEVER used based on the subscription handling. 

Of({}) will call next and complete callback of subscriber.

Of() or EMPTY will call only complete callback of subscriber.

throwError will call error callback of subscriber.

NEVER won't can any callback of subscriber.

Answer (score 11):

Inspired by @RVP answer I have found out that it's possible to cut the chain with an error in the same simple way using `Observable.throw()`

```
//...
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (stopThisRequestWithError) {
        return Observable.throw('Error message');
    } else {
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

This avoids fulfilling response promises with undefined values.

Comment: In a scenario, where let's say I have two rxJS requests executing simultaneously to the backend, and I want to stop one of them, how can I do that with interceptor?

Comment: This answer (using throwError in the current version of RxJS) was the only thing that worked for me. EMPTY, as others suggested, had some nasty side effects as the code that was waiting on the results never ran.

Comment: `throwError(...)` now

Comment: @Codehan25 just a variable that I have came up with, you need to set the condition by yourself depending on needs.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I think i am late to the party but wanna share some additional knowledge

If you wanna cancel requests after a certain timeout you can use rxjs timeout operator in intercepter, and it will work for every requests.

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> 
    {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(timeout(30000), 
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      return throwError({ error: error.name, message: error.message});
    })) as Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To Angular 6, you need can user the following structure to return a empty Observable:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {empty} from 'rxjs/internal/Observer';

//...

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (stopThisRequest) {
        return Observable.create(empty);
    } else {
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you pls elaborate what is Observable.create(empty);

Comment: Empty is a RxJs Observer that cancel the request but still return a valid Observer. You can add him to you project with this import: import {empty} from 'rxjs/internal/Observer';

Answer (score 0):

@RVP's code will work, We can do one more thing for same.

add `return` only, it will also work

```
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
          if(helper.isTokenExpired(tokenVal)){
              return;
          }
        .
        . <{code}>
        .

    }
```

Comment: This didn't work for me - got the error "You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable."

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, there is more optimal way to handle the error with custom response

```
import { throwError, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  if (authFailedDummy(request)) {
    return throwError(new Error('Authorization error: The request did not go through'));
  }
  return next.handle(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to implement a read-only interceptor where:

1. the request would be cancelled
   => to do so let's *unsubscribe* it thanks to the `takeUntil` operator
2. the request would end with a client error
   (so that NgRx handlers would not indefinitely hang in a loading state)
   => to do so let's throw an error thanks to the `throwError` observable
3. the request would actually *leave* the browser before its cancellation
   => to do so let's *defer* the cancellation thanks to the `timer(0)` observable

Here is my complete and over-commented implementation, using Angular 15:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
  if (someCondition) {
    // this emitter will be responsible for canceling the request as well as throwing the cancel error
    const cancelEmitter$ = new Subject<void>();

    // use `takeUntil` operator to unsubscribe to the `next.handle(req)` observable as soon as the emitter emits
    // this will have the effect of canceling the request
    const nextWithCancel$ = next.handle(req).pipe(takeUntil(cancelEmitter$));

    // use `switchMap` operator to switch to the `throwError` observable to throw the cancel error as soon as the emitter emits
    const throwCancelError$ = cancelEmitter$.pipe(switchMap(() =>
      throwError(() => new HttpErrorResponse({
        error: new ErrorEvent('cancelled request due to read-only interceptor'), // client error
        status: 0,
        statusText: 'CANCELLED',
      }))
    ));

    // use the `timer(0)` observable to defer the cancel emission right after the `next.handle(req)` observable's subscription by Angular
    // this will have the effect of letting the request leaves the browser, but cancelling it just after
    const triggerCancel$ = timer(0).pipe(switchMap(() => {
      cancelEmitter$.next(); // cancel request + throw error
      cancelEmitter$.complete(); // avoid memory leaks
      return EMPTY;
    }));

    // subscribe to both trigger & next & throw observables (`triggerCancel$` & `throwCancelError$` never emit)
    return merge(triggerCancel$, nextWithCancel$, throwCancelError$);
  }
  ...
}
```

The request leaves the browser just before being cancelled:

[image: request cancellation in action]

Answer (score -9):

```
let sub = this.http.get(url, {headers: reqHeaders})
            .subscribe(
                (res) => {
                    res = res.json();
                }
            );

sub.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its not the solution!

Comment: This can't be done in an interceptor since you don't have the subscription, but the HttpRequest.

Comment: @maximeMorin, yes you can, if you can return an Observable, you can return an Observable that tells your subscriber to unsubscribe.