# Return from interceptor

Tags: angular, http, interceptor

I am developing Angular 2 application, and I have HTTP interceptor already created in application. In some cases, I want to return from interceptor, for example I do not want to make some calls to server if user is not authorized. I just want to stop request by returning the right Observable so that the other requests may proceed and application does not break. I have tried to create some Empty Observable but it breaks my app. Basically, I would like to create null object-like behavior. Could someone help me?

```
get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    if(!isAuthorized()) {
       //here a I want to create return value that will stop request 
       //but app will continue to run on the same page
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433953/how-to-cancel-current-request-in-interceptor-angular-4

Comment: Thank you. I have tried all of the suggested solutions but none of them works for me.

Comment: How are you calling `get(...)`?

Comment: In the module where is needed, Interceptor is listed in providers array of a module. It then calls get automatically on GET request. I am fairly new to Interceptors, this interceptor was already created for me and I am modifying it, I apologize for badly formulated question from the start.

Comment: Share the interceptor class..

Comment: In what way does your app break?

Comment: Thank you all. We have decided to fix problem some other way in our system, so that Interceptor remains the same. Thanks again.