# Catching Internal Server Error (500) on AngularJS / Cordova App

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova

I have a cordova app using angular js. Every once in a while we get this error:[image]

I was wondering how I would be able to listen for this so I can make a custom pop up instead of the default iOS one.  I have tried the answers from these links but couldn't get them to work:

[AngularJS: Catch all response status 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149572/angularjs-catch-all-response-status-500)